# Facebook Access Token for Automatic Script (get token every time script runs)

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth-2.0, facebook-oauth

I'm trying to set up a script that will run every day at 7am and pull our organization's ad data from Facebook. I got the actual Python script totally working: 
(I used my actual app id, app secret, account, and user access token instead of X's of course, and wound up storing it in a csv but didn't copy that part of the code because it isn't relevant)

```
from facebookads.objects import AdAccount
from facebookads.api import FacebookAdsApi
import pandas as pd

my_app_id = 'XXX'
my_app_secret = 'XXX'
my_access_token = 'XXX'
FacebookAdsApi.init(my_app_id, my_app_secret, my_access_token)

account = AdAccount('act_XXX')
params = {
    'data_columns':['adgroup_id','date_start','date_stop','campaign_name','reach', 'frequency', 'impressions', 'clicks', 'unique_clicks', 'ctr', 'unique_ctr', 'spend', 'cpm','cpp', 'cpc', 'actions'],
'date_preset': 'last_90_days',
    }

stats = account.get_report_stats(params=params);
print (stats)
```

The problem is that this token expires every 60 minutes. I need a way that I won't have to modify this program every day to get authenticated in Facebook. I realize that the above token is the USER token. I've tried the App Token (which is "app_id|app_secret") and I've even gotten Python to give it to me through a request:

```
import requests
r = requests.get("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?    client_id={{my_id}}&client_secret={{my_secret}}&grant_type=client_credentials")
#print r.headers
token = r.content
print (token)
```

But it won't take this as the actual token. It only gives me the ad data when I manually put in the USER token. If I'm understanding the situation correctly, I need either

1) A permanent token (Don't think this exists)

or 2) a way to request the (user?) token from the Facebook API every time the Python script runs.

This is Facebook's page on access tokens (where I got the code from) https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens I know there is the extended 60 day token but that won't work because then we still have to manually go in and change it every 60 days. The idea is to have the script run automatically and not have to re-code it for each run.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 60 days is all you can get for user access tokens. And you need user interaction to get a new one. There is no way around this. _“The idea is to have the script run automatically and not have to re-code it for each run”_ – if your script runs daily, then this is hardly “for each run”.

Comment: If you like, you can add an additional step that checks the expiry time of the token from your script – and if it is less than, say X days, send an email to the user that they have to go login and get a new token. If you automate this clever enough, getting a new token, extending it and storing it somewhere could be done with a couple of clicks.

Comment: Thanks I appreciate the feedback. I will go the 60-day token and email reminder route. :)